# Encryption on the bytes of a .exe file corrupting

Tags: java

My .exe file seems to be corrupting when I write the bytes back encrypted.

```
  static byte[] read(String inputfn){
        send("Reading file: " + inputfn);
        File file = new File(inputfn);
        send("File size: " + file.length());
        byte[] result = null;
        try {
          InputStream input =  new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
          result = readclose(input);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
          send(ex);
        }
        return result;
      }

  static byte[] readclose(InputStream input2){ 
        bk = new byte[1000*1024]; 
        ByteArrayOutputStream result = null; 
        try  {
          try {
            result = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bk.length);
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while(bytesRead != -1){
              bytesRead = input2.read(bk);
              if(bytesRead > 0){
                result.write(bk, 0, bytesRead);
              }
            }
              crypted = xe.encrypt(bk, 1, 100);
             // send(crypted);
              send("Writing new file: "+ DIR_OUT.toString());
             // OP = crypted.getBytes();
             // byte[] PP = result.getBytes();
              //write(bk,DIR_OUT);

          }
          finally {
            input2.close();
          }
        }
        catch (IOException ex){
          send(ex);
        }
        return result.toByteArray();
      }
```

The variable bk is equal to the bytes being put back in the file, how do I make this the length of the bytes of the file being inputted? I only want it to encrypt the bytes in the file. I had to make it 1000 so all the file bytes could be encrypted, otherwise it would only encrypt some.

Also once the bytes are encrypted, in order to make the .exe work, would I have to convert back to base64string before writing? (Would that completely cancel the encryption)

Answer (score 0):

bk is just your buffer. Why do you encrypt that? What you want to encrypt is the content of result.
crypted = xe.encrypt(result.toByteArray(), 1, 100);
If you do it this way it also doesn't matter how big bk is.

Comment: That worked thanks, but how would I apply the encryption to the file and allow it to still be executable? I've tried write(crypted.getByes(), file)

My write method works and outputs the file, but it looks like the encryption corrupts it. How would I make this still work, but encrypted still.

Comment: What do you expect? You destroy the file by encryption, you must decrypt it befire excuting

Comment: Then how are crypters made to bypass AV etc? The bytes in the file need to be encrypted, but if I need to decrypt them before opening, it will still be the same as the original?